# How do I make a caption start at a future section

Tags: captions

If I write,

```
 \caption{Test}
```

the caption reads as,
     "Figure 1: Test"

I want it to read as,
     "Figure 13.1: Test"

where the 13 is the chapter number I am working on. I do not have any of the previous chapters on file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Any hack you'll do to achieve that you have to revert if the document is merged. Do you really want this?

Comment: If you have no other chapters yet the chapter is `1` and not `13`. Who says that the chapter will be the chapter numbered 13 in the long end?

Answer (score 1):

Use `\numberwithin` from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Test}  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the counter by:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
```

edit: This (`{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}`) is actually the default setting for `books`.

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter 1}
Some text.
\begin{figure}
  test
  \caption{mycaption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```